# Find $a,b,c$ such that the equation $ax^2+a=by^2+b=cz^2+c$ has infinitely many integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Do there exist $3$ positive integers $a,b,c~(a<b<c),$ such that the equation
$$ax^2+a=by^2+b=cz^2+c$$
has infinitely many integer solutions $x,y,z$ ?

Comment: Something tells me that if there is going to be it should be something like $a=r$, $b=rs$, $c=rs^4$, for $s$ not a square. This is such that the general solutions of the Pell equations related to these are computed by powers $M+\sqrt{s}N$ for the two equations. Otherwise different radicals appear and it seems unlikely one gets infinitely many solutions. But I thought about it without being careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require
$$
ax^2-cz^2=c-a\\
(ax)^2-(ac)z^2=a(c-a)
$$
and likewise
$$
(by)^2-(bc)z^2=b(c-b)
$$

According to Bennett "[On the number of solutions of simultaneous Pell equations](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper10.pdf)" this can only have finitely many solutions unless
$$
acb(c-b) = bca(c-a)
$$
that is, unless $b=a$, so the answer to your question is negative.